# Как обрабатывать 404 страницу если на сайте ЧПУ ссылки?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, .htaccess, backend

У меня на сайте все ссылки являются ЧПУ, т.е `site.com/film-box`, **но из-за этого не работает 404 страница**.

Т.е когда пишешь `site.com/рандомныебуквы` - **сайт принимает её как отдельную чпу страницу.**

Как это исправить?

Когда есть второй слеш `site.com/рандомныебуквы/рандомныебуквы` - **404 вызывается.**

Обработка URL:

```
function get_singles_by_url($url)
{
    global $db;
    $singles = $db->query("SELECT * FROM singles WHERE url = '$url'"); // URL странице
    foreach ($singles as $single) {
        return $single;
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код роутера то.

Comment: @nazarpunk, а как это сделать?

Comment: взять код роутера и выложить сюда. Или каким образом вы предлагаете решение искать не видя кода?

Comment: @nazarpunk, Я не понимаю, что за код роутера? Причём здесь роутер если это скорей всего ошибка в .htaccess или в php функциях.

Comment: Скажем по другому - покажите код, который обрабатывает значение ссылки

Comment: @NikitaGaladiy, как узнать?

Comment: @OTMEHA, сайт на самописном движке или на каком-то определенном?

Comment: @NikitaGaladiy, на самописном. PHP

Comment: @OTMEHA и как на вашем самописном движке идёт обработка url?

Comment: @nazarpunk, написал в теме выше. в описании.

Comment: как только вы поймете, что ни ".htaccess", ни "php функции" не сделают то, то вы должны сделать сами вручную, дело пойдёт быстрее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю все адреса страниц хранятся в БД?

Ну и сделайте тогда проверку

```
function get_singles_by_url($url)
{
   global $db;

   //Тут не понятно почему нет защиты от SQL Inject, но возможно вы используете какую-то библиотку где есть предварительная подготовка к отправке запроса.
   $singles = $db->query("SELECT * FROM singles WHERE url = '$url'"); // URL странице

   if(empty($singles))
   {
       //Тут выводим 404 ошибку или возвращаем то что нужно что бы ее вывести
   }
   else
   {
       //Тут тоже не понятно что за цикл??? При первом проходе он будет остановлен
       //Я так понимаю тут класс БД c использованием PDO тогда просто можно вернуть return $singles[0];
      foreach ($singles as $single) {
          return $single;
   }
}
```

Comment: Если тут класс БД c использованием PDO тогда нельзя просто вернуть return $singles[0]

Comment: Опять же смотря как написан класс c БД

Comment: Ну я согласен что в сети много кривого кода бегает, но логичным будет предположить что у автора ванильная PDO::query()